# HTML ignores css file

Tags: html, css, sass

I have HTML file with  `<link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/style.min.css">` in head and my custom.css file.
Why my custom.css file is ignored - I cannot style image or padding while using devtools in the browser I can simply manipulate it (?)
It seems like I could only use inline styles which is unacceptable.

I have only two css files in head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Zadanie 1</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/style.min.css"> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/custom.css">        
</head>
```

Comment: The best we can do with this is give general debugging tips, you'll need to include significantly more information.

Comment: Can you share more details? It's pretty hard to guess what is happening at your site, maybe the file is not found, the CSS is malformed, you've styled the wrong elements,.....

Comment: are you sure your href filepath is accurate?

Comment: How do you know it's ignoring the CSS file?

Comment: For sure, if the path is correct, the second loaded file overrides the first one. Always think of the cascades.

Answer (score 1):

If your file is named 'custom.css' then you need to include that in the href.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/custom.css">
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you include your css file in your header?
It should look like this:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="custom.css">
</head>
```

Also make sure that the file is located in the same folder as the HTML file unless you change the href to point to a subfolder.